# Shared Session state with SQLSERVER

Tags: session-state

We are using Sitecore 7.2 and trying to implement Shared Session state with SQLSERVER. When we switch to SQLserver mode from InProc , we don't see any sessions created in the "[ASPStateTempSessions]" table. We are using the below web.config entry.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="30000" sqlConnectionString="data source=XXX;Network Library=XXX;user id=XXX;password=XXX" cookieless="false" /> .
```

Has anyone implemented a Shared Session state with SQLSERVER for Sitecore. Please provide pointers.

Comment: Have you added the connection string entry? you can refer https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--configuring-a-shared-session-state-database-using-sql.html

Comment: Thanks @HimanshuAgarwal. I am susing sc7.2 and I don't see the sharedSessionState config entry or the Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Config file. Do you suggest to try the same in web.config file.

Comment: I believe you have to add a entry in connectionstring.config file. refer the blog link that I have shared

Comment: Are you doing this on CD or CM servers?

Comment: Above changes needs to be done in CD because session needs to be shared between different CD.
https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/out-of-process-session-options-for-sitecore-7-2/

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy AmitKumar Himanshu Agarwal for your help. I was able to resolve this. Actaully the issue was with the network port of SQL Database. SItecore was not able to connect to the SQL database. So, we specifically opened the port for connection and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MarkCassidy @AmitKumar @Himanshu Agarwal for your help. I was able to resolve this. Actually the issue was with the network port of SQL Database. Sitecore was not able to connect to the SQL database at the default port. So, we specifically opened the port for connection and it worked.